# Reference error: myFunc is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a problem with my function that is showing type error. In summary I've the code like below:

```
function myFunc(){
    alert('test');
}

//if I run myFunc() here then it runs
myFunc();//alerts test

$('.selector').click(function(){
    myFunc();//type error:: how to call the function?
});
```

Sorry, if this is a stupid question.

---

**Update**

I've just reproduced my key problem:

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dh3cz/)

```
window.onload = function(){
    function myFunc(){
    alert('test');
}
}

$('.test').click(function(){
    myFunc();//doesn't alert test
});
```

Comment: Please provide more information to discover the problem, as your example should work perfectly well.

Comment: Is this really your code? After the last edit it's ok. Can you provide more context or a demo on jsfiddle? Can you provide you console error text?

Comment: [I cannot reproduce your problem](http://jsbin.com/soqahotu/1/edit?html,output). Whatever it is, it doesn't appear in your test case.

Comment: oh! sorry not type error. it's saying reference error.

Comment: In this way muFunc is inside the onload scope, so it will not be visibile outside it...define it in the global scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`myFunc` is scoped to the function it is declared inside.

Move it outside or move the event handler assignment inside.

```
// Define this in a script element after the element you are trying to select

function myFunc(){
    alert('test');
}
$('.test').click(function(){
    myFunc();
});

// or use this anywhere

window.onload = function(){
    function myFunc(){
        alert('test');
    }
    $('.test').click(function(){
        myFunc();
    });
}

// but if you are going to use jQuery, you might as well go the whole hog
// and also just wait for the DOM to be ready instead of allowing time for images
// and other external resources to load too.

$(function(){
    function myFunc(){
        alert('test');
    }
    $('.test').click(function(){
        myFunc();
    });
});
```

Comment: is there not any method that I could call the function from that.

Answer (score -1):

Your function is defined in the scope of another function and is unreachable. You should put it in the scope of the calling function, e.g.:

```
function myFunc() {
    alert('test');
}

$(function() {
    $('.test').click(function() {
        myFunc();
    });
});
```